# VBA - Copy Paste Userform automatically

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Is there a way to copy paste a Userform automatically?

In my Workbook i need about 10 or even 25 identical Userforms, each of them stands for one assignment.

Do i really have to rename and import each Userform manually or is there an automatically way to copy past, rename and import the Form when it is needed?

Comment: Why do you need 10 or 25 and not just one?

Comment: Because each Form stands for ONE assignment. If i add a new assignment i still want to watch the other assignments

Comment: You could always programmatically create each userform?

Comment: Do these UserForms have the exact same look?

Comment: Or show multiple instance of the same userform rather than using the default instance.  `Set f1 = New UserForm1: f1.Show: Set f2 = New UseForm1: f2.Show`

Comment: @TimWilliams y. thats what I was targetting at.

Comment: I will try it .. thanks